# How are t-butyl substituents named according to IUPAC nomenclature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the IUPAC name of this structure?

[image: Skeletal formula of compound CC(C)(C)C1C(CCC)CCC(CCCCCCC)CCCC1]

I've actually came up with two names, the first one is "1-tert-butyl-5-heptyl-2-propylcyclononane" and the other one is "1-(1,1-dimethylethyl)-5-heptyl-2-propyl-cyclononane". I'm confused which one is right or if both are correct.

Comment: @KarstenTheis I've actually came up with two names, the first one is "1-tert-butyl-5-heptyl-2-propylcyclononane" and the other one is "1-(1,1-dimethylethyl)-5-heptyl-2-propyl-cyclononane". I'm confused which one is right or if both are correct.

Comment: So your question is not about how to name it, but rather whether the tBu group should be written as "tert-butyl" or "1,1-dimethylethyl".

Comment: Note also that there should not be a hyphen directly before cyclononane; one of your proposed names is correct in this regard and the other isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)*](https://doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069) (**P-57.1.2**), the preferred prefix for $\ce{-C(CH3)3}$ is "*tert*-butyl".

As for where it comes in the name:

> **P-14.5** Alphanumerical order
>   [...] Alphanumerical order is applied as follows in organic nomenclature. Nonitalic Roman letters are considered first, unless used as locants or part of a compound or composite locant [...]

so the prefix *tert* is not considered (except in more complicated cases, cf. **P-14.5.3**). Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name for the molecule in question is **1-*tert*-butyl-5-heptyl-2-propylcyclononane**. Note that there are no parentheses around *tert*-butyl.

Be warned: *tert*-butyl has received special treatment from IUPAC on this front. Other non-systematic prefixes have fallen from favour, most notably isopropyl, *sec*-butyl, and isobutyl. The preferred prefixes are respectively propan-2-yl, butan-2-yl, and 2-methylpropyl.